# How to convert the result of an Integer * Integer multiplication to Double?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, typeclass, algebraic-data-types

I am just learning Haskell and want to develop my first recursive ADT.

My datatype `Figure` should be able to represent arbitrary combinations of rectangles and circles, and the method `area` should calculate a figure's total area (ignoring overlaps).

The problem is that for e.g. rectangles, width and height are `Integer`, while the result of area should be `Double` (or at least a floating point number).

```
data Figure = Rect { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, width :: Integer, height :: Integer}
            | Circle { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, radius :: Integer}
            | CombiFigure Figure Figure
            deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

area :: Figure -> Double
area (Rect _ _ w h) = (w * h) -- Integer * Integer, does not work
area (Circle _ _ r) = (pi * r * r) -- (Floating a => a) * Integer * Integer, does not work
area (CombiFigure first second) = (area first) + (area second) -- Double * Double, works
```

Can you give me a direction how to solve this? It is not mandatory that result is `Double`, but some floating point number for circle area calculation.

Comment: see https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @Jean-Baptiste Yunés I was able to solve this by using `fromIntegral` and `fromInteger` found [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers):

```
data Figure = Rect { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, width :: Integer, height :: Integer}
            | Circle { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, radius :: Integer}
            | CombiFigure Figure Figure
            deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

area :: Figure -> Double
area (Rect _ _ w h) = (fromIntegral w * fromIntegral h) -- Method 1: using fromIntegral
area (Circle _ _ r) = (pi * fromInteger r * fromInteger r) -- Method 2: using fromInteger
area (CombiFigure first second) = (area first) + (area second)
```